# Trying to populate the field but it's not happening

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-populate

i have two models posts and users,and i want to populate the user field in posts but for some reasons its not working

post schema

```
import mongoose, { Schema, mongo } from "mongoose";


const postSchema = new Schema({
    description : {
        type : String,
        required : true,
        maxLength : [250 , "You can type upto only 250 characters"]
    },
    img : {type  : String},
    date : {
        type : Date,
        default : new Date(Date.now()),
        required : true
    },
    user : {
        type  : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref : 'User',
        required : true,
    },
    likeCount : {
        type : Number,
        required : true,
        default : 0

    }, 
    comments : {type : [{
        text : String,
        postedBy :{
            type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref : "User"
        }  
    }],
    default : []
    }
})

export const Post = mongoose.model("post",postSchema)
```

users schema

```
import mongoose, { Mongoose } from "mongoose";
import { Schema } from "mongoose";


const userSchema =  new Schema({
    name : {
        type : String,
        required : true,
        unique : true
    },
    password : {
        type : String,
        required : true,
    },
    email : {
        type : String,
        required : true,
        unique : true
    },
    followingList : [{type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId , ref : "User" , unique : true}],
    followerList : [{type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId , ref : "User", unique : true}],

    followRequests : {type : [{
        userId : {
            type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref : "Users",
            required : true
        },
        isAccepted : {type : Boolean , default : false}
    }],
    default : []
    },
})

export const User = mongoose.model('User',userSchema)
```

the code for fetching posts

```
export const getAllUserPosts = async(req,res) => {
    const {id} = req.params
    const userPosts = await Post.find({user : id}).populate("user","name,_id")
    res.status(200).json(
        {
            userPosts
        }
    )
}
```

i tried eveything that was available on the web , but nothing actually helped me
it doesnt throw any error  , it actually executes , it should should the name and id of the user in the posts but it only shows the id,
i cant figure out where the actual problem occurs , even read the documentation and i dont see any issues in my code

Answer (score 0):

Your populate is not formatted correctly. `.populate("user", "name,_id")` is invalid. It looks like you meant to do name._id? All you need to populate is the fields that have a type mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId. Edit: looks like you put a comma instead of a space. That might fix it.

See below:

controller:

```
    module.exports.createBook = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const {_id, displayName} = jwt.verify(req.cookies.userToken, secret)
        const myBook = new Book(req.body)
        myBook.addedBy = _id
        myBook.addedByString = displayName
        myBook.favoritedBy.push(_id)
        let newBook = await myBook.save()
        await newBook.populate("addedBy favoritedBy")
        await User.findByIdAndUpdate(newBook.addedBy, {$push: {booksAdded: newBook._id, booksFavorited: newBook._id}})
        res.json({ book: newBook })
        // console.log("inside try")
    }catch(err){
        console.log(`inside catch`, err)
        res.status(400).json({ message: "Something went worng creating a book", error: err }) //error isnt specific to either try line
    }
}
```

model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const { findOneUser } = require('../controllers/user.controller')

const BookSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Title is required"],
        minlength: [2, "Title must be at least 2 characters"]
    },
    author: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Author is required"],
        minlength: [2, "Author must be at least 2 characters"]
    },
    addedByString: {
        type: String
    },
    addedBy: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User",
        required: [true, "Added-By field is required"]
    },
    favoritedBy: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User"
    }]
},
    { timestamps: true }
)

module.exports = mongoose.model('Book', BookSchema)
```